# VmWare OVFTool: deploying with --nodisks still creates VmWare with disk. Any suggestion?

Tags: vmware, disk

I am using below  OVA deploy command ::

```
ovftool --acceptAllEulas -vf=abc --chunkSize=2gb --noSSLVerify --noDisks --name=hostname  --network=network1  -ds=datacentre1--sourceType=OVA  --viCpuResource=0:0:0 --viMemoryResource=0:0:0  --powerOn "abc.ova"   vi://target_location
```

Eventhough I am specifying the --noDisks option , the default image disk gets created. 
I want to create the Vmware without this default image disk.

Answer (score 0):

The noDisks option will still create the disks, those disks just won't contain any data.

Pulled from the docs:

> Creates and uploads the virtual machine or vApps but does not
>   upload any disk files. Disks are created empty. (Disables disk
>   conversion.)

Comment: thank you. I have achieved through java coding to delete the disk and upload with user selected size.